# Buggy behavior when turning ignored tag into synonym of favorited tag

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, tag-synonyms

I just wondered why some plugin-related questions were grayed out, while I even chose `<plugins>` one of my favorite tags.

I then took a look at the favorite and ignored tags, and found `<plugins>` not in the favorite list anymore but in the ignored list instead.

So, what happened, in short:

- I favorited `<plugins>`, while ignoring `<woocommerce>`;
- `<woocommerce>` just got turned into a `<plugins>` synonym;
- the *system* then apparently found `<plugins>` in both lists, and respected only the last occurrence (i.e., ignore).

#### Feature request

When turning an existing tag `<tag-SYNONYM>` into a synonym for `<tag-MASTER>`, the system should check if `<tag-SYNONYM>` is ignored **and** `<tag-MASTER>` is favorited.
If so, the tag should be removed from the ignore list.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: "woocommerce" got turned into a synonym of "plugins"? When/why did that happen? Is that to prevent it from being added to future questions?

Comment: @ChipBennett As to be seen [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all), Rarst made it happen, on December 12th. Why, I don't know as well. I couldn't find anything in the woo questions on meta...

Comment: See [this chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/conversation/rarst-and-toscho-argue-about-merging-woocommerce-into-plugins).

Comment: @toscho Oh, I'm shocked by both how very damn fitting your Hitchhiker analogy is, and that ... it got ignored nonetheless.