# Q&A for external plugins

Tags: discussion, plugins

Firstly, sorry for the awkward title. I just couldn't come up with a short description of what this question is about.

I'm interested in how you feel about the following *situation*.
Someone involved in the development of a particular WordPress plugin posts a question and answers it.

Of course, this is nothing more than Q&A any other WP-specific thing. I'm asking this here on Meta, because it, at some point, incorporates advertising/promoting the particular plugin.

Altogether, there are a lot of people, who would take advantage of this:

- the users of that particular plugin, as they are provided with frequently and/or hard-to-figure-out-on-your-own question—which even come with a sound solution;
- the developers of the plugin, as the plugin is being promoted in some sort of way;
- but also *WPD* (as in *WordPress Development*, also known as *WordPress Answers*).

The *Stack* takes advantages in that the knowledge base grows (by questions **and** according answers, that is). The plugin developers could (and **if** they use WPD to Q&A on the plugin) **will** link to WPD on the plugin pages and related articles, sites or whatever. Most likely this will also lead to new users (who maybe even don't know about WPD or SE in general).

This directly leads to another interesting question: Should these questions (if you/we decide to allow them) be tagged `[plugin-whatever]`? Should this be up to the one who asks (and answers) the question?

Of course, I'm aware that this is the exact opposite of [Merge all plugin-* tags into [plugins]?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/merge-all-plugin-tags-into-plugins). However, this question is still *active*, and based on the votes (7 up, 1 down) there are not many people either interested or determined—compared to the 51 up and 1 down votes of the site name question, for example.

So, what are your thoughts? What did I miss? Where could this *go wrong*? Why is it a great idea? Anything?

Comment: 7-10 votes is a medium to good participation rate in a meta question. from that you can tell that most high rep and highly involved people have read it and those who are interested or concerned then voted. everything with 20+ votes (as in positive/upvotes) touched a very large audience or were shown publically (on the main site) by our mods. The linked question currently has 8 (+7/-1) votes and I haven't voted as I still ain't got a +/- opinion on it. And I'm sure others have the same problem and therefore stayed away from voting.

Comment: You mean for webdevelopers to use [plugin-whatever] as (sort of) their helpdesk?

Comment: @ScubaKay Yep, that (sort of) right. ;) I'm talking here primarily about questions asked (and directly answered) by plugin authors. Of course, these questions _could_ be restricted to the respective plugins' support forums. But that is exactly why I posted this question. If users find answers about some plugins, maybe they will register, ask whatever other WordPress-related stuff, and/or contribute to this stack by answering questions...